# looping through variable names according to their prefix in R

Tags: r, loops

I have to carry out a number of comparisons, and I was wondering how to automate the overall procedure. Suppose I have only the following variables:

```
age location serial weight height age_n location_n serial_n weight_n height_n
```

I want to compare

```
data[weight != weight_n,c("serial ","weight","weight_n") , drop = F]
```

for each and every variable.
How can I loop over all the variables?

I was trying

```
for (nam in colnames(df)) {
  data['nam' != 'nam'_n,c("serial ",'nam','nam'_n) , drop = F]           
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an alternate.  Note you should only loop through the column names w/o the `_n` (hence the `grep` in the `for` section):

```
for(nam in colnames(df)[-grep("_n$", colnames(df))]) {
  data[
    data[[nam]] != data[[paste0(nam, "_n"]], 
    c("serial", nam, paste0(nam, "_n")
  ]  
}
```

Comment: `x.1 <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5) , a=c(1,2,3,4,5), b=c(1,2,3,4,5))
x.2 <- data.frame(id=c(1,2,3,4,5) ,id_n=c(1,2,3,4,5), a_n=c(1,1,2,3,4), b_n=c(1,1,99,3,4))
df <- merge(x.1,x.2,by="id")
for(nam in colnames(df)[-grep("_n$", colnames(df))]) {
  df[df[[nam]] != df[[paste0(nam, "_n")]],   c("id", nam, paste0(nam, "_n"))   , drop = F ]  
}`
Gives no output

Comment: @Keniajin, if you want to see the output on screen you need to `print` it because commands run inside the `for` loop don't print by default (i.e. `print(data[....])).